# Some regular open sets of the Cantor space $2^\omega$ are not closed.

Tags: general-topology, logic

The Cantor space is the set $2^\omega$ equipped with the product topology (where $2=\{0,1\}$ has the discrete topology).

I'm encountering some difficulties in understanding this proof (splitted into a list by me):

> **Proposition.** Some regular open sets of $2^\omega$ are not closed.
>
> *Proof.* A counterexample is given by *Odd* and *Even*, where *Odd* (resp. *Even*) is the set of sequences in $2^\omega$ that differ from $0^\omega$ and start with an odd (resp. even) number of zeros. These two sets are open, disjoint and
>
> 1. their closures intersect only in $0^\omega$.
> 2. In particular, $0^\omega$ is the unique point in the closure of *Odd* and *Even* such that no open set containing it has a dense intersection with *Odd* or a dense intersection with *Even*.
> 3. While any element of *Odd* (resp. *Even*) has a clopen neighboorhood fully contained in *Odd* (resp. *Even*).
> 4. This means that *Odd* and *Even* are regular and open,
>
> but they are not closed.

In particular, it seems that the proof makes use of some sort of "intuitive understanding" of how the Cantor space works, which I can't grasp. I know that open sets are basically the ones where only a finite number of "entries" are fixed, and that $2^\omega$ is compact, Hausdorff and $0$-dimensional. But I don't understand:

- How do closures of sets in $2^\omega$ look like in general? And in particular, what are the closures of *Odd* and *Even*?
- How do closed sets look like in $2^\omega$?
- How do clopen sets look like in $2^\omega$?
- Why is (1) interesting/needed for the rest of the proof?
- Why is (2) true?

I understand why (3) is true and also why (4) follows by (3) (it's a characterization of regular open sets, even though we actually need just open neighborhoods, not clopen).

Maybe everything becomes more clear if we look at $2^\omega$ as the metric space with the well-known metric? I would be happy if someone could answer my questions and/or give any reference where I can learn how to better figure the Cantor space.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It’s not really possible to give a general description of closures that’s significantly simpler than the definition of closure.

I’ll use $O$ and $E$ for your sets $Odd$ and $Even$. Suppose that $x=\langle x_n:n\in\omega\rangle\in\operatorname{cl}O$. For each $n\in\omega$ let $B_n(x)=\{y\in 2^\omega:y_k=x_k\text{ for all }k\le n\}$; then $\{B_n(x):n\in\omega\}$ is a local base (of clopen sets) at $x$. Thus, for each $n\in\omega$ we have $B_n(x)\cap O\ne\varnothing$. If $x\ne 0^\omega$, let $m\in\omega$ be minimal such that $x_m=1$; since $B_m(x)\cap O\ne\varnothing$, there is a $y\in O$ such that $y_k=x_k$ for all $k\le m$, which means that $m$ must be odd, and therefore $x\in O$. Could $x$ be $0^\omega$? Yes: for each $n\in\omega$ we can find a $y\in O$ that begins with more than $n+1$ zeroes, and then $y\in B_n(0^\omega)\cap O$. We’ve just proved that $\operatorname{cl}O=O\cup\{0^\omega\}$.

Essentially the same argument shows that $\operatorname{cl}E=E\cup\{0^\omega\}$. Thus, neither $O$ nor $E$ is closed, and hence neither is clopen. Moreover, $(\operatorname{cl}O)\cap\operatorname{cl}E=\{0^\omega\}$. To complete the proof, we must show that $O$ and $E$ are not just open, but regular open. This is where (2) is supposed to come in, but I think that it’s unnecessarily confusing, so I’ll do it differently.

To show that $O$ is regular open, for instance, we must show that $\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}O=O$, i.e., that

$$\operatorname{int}\big(O\cup\{0^\omega\}\big)=O\;.$$

Since $O$ is open, this amounts to showing that $0^\omega\notin\operatorname{int}\big(O\cup\{0^\omega\}\big)$. But we just saw that for each $n\in\omega$ there are points $y\in B_n(0^\omega)\cap O$ and $z\in B_n(0^\omega)\cap E$, and $O\cap E=\varnothing$, so $0^\omega$ has no open nbhd contained in either $O$ or $E$; in other words, $0^\omega\notin\operatorname{int}\big(O\cup\{0^\omega\}\big)$ and $0^\omega\notin\operatorname{int}\big(E\cup\{0^\omega\}\big)$, so $\operatorname{int}\big(O\cup\{0^\omega\}\big)=O$, $\operatorname{int}\big(E\cup\{0^\omega\}\big)=E$, and $O$ and $E$ are both regular open.

The actual statement of (2) is unnecessarily opaque in my opinion; let me see if I can clear it up a bit. Suppose that $0^\omega$ had an open nbhd $U$ such that $O\cap U$ was dense in $U$. Then

$$U\subseteq\operatorname{cl}U=\operatorname{cl}(O\cap U)\subseteq\operatorname{cl}O=O\cup\{0^\omega\}=2^\omega\setminus E\;,$$

contradicting the fact that $0^\omega\in\operatorname{cl}E$. A similar contradiction would arise if $0^\omega$ had an open nbhd $U$ such that $E\cap U$ was dense in $U$. All of this is really just an unnecessarily roundabout way of demonstrating that $0^\omega$ has no open nbhd contained in $O\cup\{0^\omega\}$ or $E\cup\{0^\omega\}$ and hence that it’s not in the interior of either of these sets.

Closed sets are simply the complements of open sets, and open sets are the sets that are the unions of basic open sets of the form $B_n(x)$ for $n\in\omega$ and $x\in 2^\omega$. It’s not much easier to pin down the clopen sets.

Comment: Wow, awesome answer! :)

Comment: Clopen basis elements are exactly the sets of sequences with an initial segment. If visualizing as a tree they are a homeomorphic copy of the space itself.

Comment: Exhaustive and precise answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: @aerdna91: You're very welcome.

Comment: @Konrad: That depends entirely on what base you choose. The natural product base contains many other clopen sets. The base derived by homeomorphism from the intersection with the middle-thirds Cantor set of open intervals in $\Bbb R$ with rational endpoints includes many sets that are not clopen.

Comment: @Brian All you'll have are finite unions of these clopen cylinders to form all clopen sets in the standard product topology. This is also the canonical basis for the Cantor Space. Especially convenient when relating to the definition of zero-dimensional.

Comment: @Konrad: I’ve been a set-theoretic topologist for over 40 years; I know what you’ll have. And whether it’s ‘the’ canonical base for the Cantor space depends on context, though I grant that it’s usually the best choice; that is, after all, why I used it in my answer. But *finite unions of basic clopen sets*, whether from that base or from the canonical product base, simply doesn’t give a great deal of intuitive insight of the kind that seemed wanted here.

Answer (score 6):

Here's my intuitive picture of closures in $2^\omega$:

First, an exercise. A **tree** is a subset of $2^{<\omega}$ - that is, a set of finite binary sequences - which is closed downwards (if $\sigma\in T$ and $\tau\prec\sigma$, then $\tau\in T$). A **path** through a tree $T$ is an $f\in 2^\omega$ such that every initial segment of $f$ is in $T$. For instance, if $T$ is the set of all finite binary strings which don't contain "1" - so, $T=\{0, 00, 000, . . . 
\}$ - then the string "$00000. . .$ " is a path through $T$.

*Exercise.* If $X$ is the set of paths through some tree $T$, then $X$ is closed.

Now let's talk about closures. Given any set $X\subseteq 2^\omega$, there is a tree $T_X$ associated to $X$: $$T_X=\{\sigma: \exists f\in X(\sigma\prec f)\},$$ that is, $T_X$ is the tree of all initial segments of elements of $X$. Then it turns out (**exercise**) that the set $Y$ of paths through $T_X$ is exactly the closure of $X$.

For example, let $X$ be the set of all infinite binary strings which contain only finitely many "$0$"s. Then $T_X$ is all of $2^{<\omega}$: given *any* finite binary string $\sigma$, the infinite binary sequence $$\sigma111111111 . . .$$ is in $X$; so by definition of $T_X$, each finite binary string $\sigma$ is in $T_X$. But then the set of paths through $T_X$ is all of $2^\omega$.

I find trees easy to picture and draw examples of - even though they're infinite objects, they're not too nasty. By the way, if you prove the bolded exercise above, you'll have shown:

*Corollary*: A set $X\subseteq 2^\omega$ is closed iff $X$ is the set of paths through some tree.

And conversely, a set $Y$ is open iff $Y$ is the set of infinite binary sequences which are *not* paths through some tree.

Comment: Very very nice and well explained! I love this answer. Also thank you for the examples.

Comment: @NoahSchweber By '$X$ is closed' you mean 'closed in the Cantor space'?

Comment: @MadHatter Yes, since Cantor space is the space under consideration.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes, of course :). But you also used the notion of a tree being closed set (downwards), and I just wanted to clarify it. Thanks!

Comment: @MadHatter Ah yes, that's annoying overload of terminology.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I find the exercise a bit confusing. Here's why. If you look at the full binary tree $T$, then every set of points of the Cantor space is a set of paths through $T$. But not every subset of the space is closed. What is that I do not understand here?

Comment: @MadHatter You need to look at the whole tree. That is, $X\subseteq 2^\omega$ is closed iff for some binary tree $T$ we have that $X$ is the set of **all** paths through $T$.

Comment: Re: the exercise, any set $X\subseteq 2^\omega$ gives us a tree $T_X\subseteq 2^{<\omega}$. Every point in $X$ is a path through $T_X$, but the converse fails in general: there may be paths through $T_X$ which are not points in $X$. The set $[T_X]$ of **all** paths through $T_X$ (which I called $Y$ above) is a closed set containing $X$, and in fact is the smallest closed set containing $X$ (in other words, $[T_X]$ is the closure of $X$).

Comment: @NoahSchweber OK, it makes sense now. Thanks a lot.